# Get all records that are ended

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table that has two columns `uid` and `isEnded`. A `uid` can occur multiple times in this table and can have the value `0` or  `1`. The value `0` can only occur one time for each unique `uid`.

For example:

---

```
| uid  | isEnded |
------------------
| 1    | 1       |
| 1    | 1       |
| 1    | 0       |
| 2    | 1       |
| 2    | 1       |
| 3    | 0       |
| 3    | 1       |
------------------
```

What I need is a query that selects all `uid`'s where all of its `isEnded` values are set to `1`.

So in the above example I should only get `uid` 2 back. Because the other two `uid`'s still have an `isEnded` set to `0`.

With what kind of query can I get such a result back? So only the `uid`s which don't have any `isEnded` values set to `0`.

Comment: which datatype is uid ? Can it have other values than 0 and 1 like null ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if all of the values should be `1` for the `uid`s you want to select, that also means that the minimum value will also be `1`:

```
SELECT uid
FROM table
GROUP BY uid
HAVING MIN(isEnded) = 1
```

Comment: i made the sample and started to give the answer.. just before i refreshed the page and BOOM.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT uid  
   FROM #Tab  
  WHERE UID NOT IN
        (SELECT uid FROM #tab WHERE isended = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
 SELECT uid
   FROM table t1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT *
           FROM table t2
          WHERE t2.uid=t1.uid
            AND isEnded=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE A 
(
    uids int,
    isEnded bit 
) 
go

 INSERT INTO A 
 VALUES (1,1),
        (1,1),
        (1,0),
        (2,1),
        (2,1),
        (3,0),
        (3,1)

 SELECT A.uids, A.isended
   FROM A
  WHERE A.uids NOT IN
        (SELECT A.uids FROM A WHERE A.isended = '0')
```

If you want distinct records then use distinct keyword in select query as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.uids, A.isended
  FROM A
 WHERE A.uids NOT IN
       (SELECT A.uids FROM A WHERE A.isended = '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

I this will do it for you:

```
 SELECT t.uid
   FROM YourTable AS t
  GROUP BY t.uid
 HAVING MIN(t.isEnded) = 1;
```

The `group by` will consider all the rows for a particular `uid` as a block.  The `having` puts a condition on that block.

**Edit**: damn! @Damien beat me to it.